# Apex record Sharing

Tags: apex

I have some Accounts and related list Account team members.
I have created custom objectX. 
I wanna share objectX records to only account team members.
How can i approach this ?? 
Kindly advice me the solution. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Account Team Members can belongs to any profile and any role . I don't want manual sharing. Kindly advice me..

Answer (score 0):

Does the account team member have lookup to users? If yes then I would suggest creating a public group with those users and then using apex managed sharing to share that public group with the objectX record.